# For a set $A$ in a linear space $\text{conv}(A)$ is convex

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently self-studying functional analysis. The other gives the following definition:

> For a set $A$ in a linear space the symbol $\text{conv}(A)$ means the set of all finite linear combination of the form $\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i$, where $x_i\in A$, $a_i\geq0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=1$.

The author then uses that $\text{conv}(A)$ is a convex set. My question is: why? Take $x,y\in\text{conv}(A)$ and any $0\leq\lambda\leq1$, we want to show that
$\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\in\text{conv}(A)$.

Taking $x,y\in\text{conv}(A)$, we have by definition $x=\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i$, where $x_i\in A$, $a_i\geq0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=1$ and $y=\sum_{i=1}^mb_ix_i$, where $x_i\in A$, $b_i\geq0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i=1$.

Consider the quantity
$\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y=\lambda \sum_{i=1}^mb_ix_i + (1-\lambda)\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i$. However, I don't see where to go from here. Maybe I am taking $x,y\in\text{conv}(A)$ incorrectly; that is,  are $x,y\in\text{conv}(A)$ of the form: $x=\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i$, where $x_i\in A$, $a_i\geq0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=1$ and $y=\sum_{i=1}^ma_ix_i$, where $x_i\in A$, $a_i\geq0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=1$?

Comment: You're not missing anything. You can expand out $\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i + (1 - \lambda) \sum_{i=1}^m b_n y_n$ (note: it's probably best if you don't use the same $x_i$s in both convex combinations) and note that the coefficients are all non-negative. Then, try summing up the coefficients. You should be able to do some factoring to show that it still comes to $1$.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Thanks, the definition was really bugging me. I think I can go from here.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Actually, getting the sum $\lambda \sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i + (1-\lambda)\sum_{i=1}^mb_iy_i$ correctly so that it is in the set $\text{conv}(A)$ is not clear to me. Namely, I don't see how to get the two sums ($\sum_{i=1}^n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^m$) to one single sum without knowing if $n\leq m$ or $m\leq n$. If you could write an answer on how to get the sum in the set $\text{conv}(A)$, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: If $x = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2$ and $y = b_1y_1 + b_2y_2$, then you also have $x = a_1x_1 +a_2x_2 + 0y_1 + 0y_2$ and $y = 0x_1 + 0x_2 + b_1y_1+b_2y_2$: so you can assume the lists $x_i$ and $y_j$ are the same. (My $y_j$ are the $x_i$ that you used for the formula for $y$: I am sticking more closely to the given definition of the convex hull.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to consider whether $m$ or $n$ are larger than each other. Suppose
\begin{align*}
x &= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i \\
y &= \sum_{i=1}^m b_i y_i,
\end{align*}
where the $a_i$s and $b_i$s are non-negative and their respective sums are $1$. Further, suppose $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y &= \lambda \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i + (1 - \lambda) \sum_{i=1}^m b_i y_i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda a_i x_i + \sum_{i=1}^m (1 - \lambda) b_i y_i, \tag{$\star$}
\end{align*}
which is a sum of $n + m$ terms. The coefficients either take the form $\lambda a_i \ge 0$, or $(1 - \lambda)b_i \ge 0$. To verify that $(\star)$ is a convex combination of the $m + n$ vectors $a_1, \ldots, a_n, b_1, \ldots, b_m$, we need only sum the coefficients to verify that the sum comes to $1$. We have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda a_i + \sum_{i=1}^n (1 - \lambda) b_i = \lambda\sum_{i=1}^n a_i + (1 - \lambda)\sum_{i=1}^m b_i = \lambda(1) + (1 - \lambda)(1) = 1.$$
This proves $(\star)$ is a convex combination of these $n + m$ vectors.